# How to debug only once and not for every host?

Tags: ansible

My task is simple:

```
- debug: msg="non-idempotent task follows"
```

but I only want it to be displayed once. At the moment the message is displayed for every host. Any ideas?

Actual output is:

```
ok: [www01.mydomain.com] => {
    "msg": "non-idempotent task follows"
}
ok: [www02.mydomain.com] => {
    "msg": "non-idempotent task follows"
}
ok: [ctrl.mydomain.com] => {
    "msg": "non-idempotent task follows"
}
```

Desired output is:

```
"msg": "non-idempotent task follows"
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add [`run_once: true`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_delegation.html#run-once) to the task.

```
- debug:
    msg: "non-idempotent task follows"
  run_once: true
```

And eventually `delegate_to: localhost` for some clarity.

Comment: accepting this .. but delegate to does not register the command as executed on localhost in the PLAY RECAP (see end of playbook run output) .. the docs say ... When “run_once” is not used with “delegate_to” it will execute on the first host, as defined by inventory, in the group(s) of hosts targeted by the play .. see http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_delegation.html#run-once .. in other words the order of host groups will determine which server the run once command will execute on

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to say. The command will run on the host that `delegate_to` specifies. If you add `delegate_to: localhost`, the default log will show for example `ok: [target01 -> localhost] => { "msg": "non-idempotent task follows" }`. You can change the task to `command: hostname`, register the output, and see which machine the command is executed on.

Comment: yes, look at the PLAY RECAP tho ... the output when you run a playbook is summarised by a PLAY RECAP .. it attributes to the wrong server (not the delegated server) ... to fix this do what i said ... e.g. instead of serverno -> serveryes you get ... serveryes without the delegation

Comment: You said "*the order of host groups will determine which server the run once command will execute on*" -- that's not true, I suggested you check with `command: hostname`. The command will execute on the delegated server. I still don't understand what you are trying to say or what bothers you.

Comment: it is true, the docs say it, ive just tested it and seen it ... again from the docs ... When “run_once” is not used with “delegate_to” it will execute on the first host, as defined by inventory, in the group(s) of hosts targeted by the play ... e.g. webservers[0] if the play targeted “hosts: webservers”. ... look at PLAY RECAP, the summary at the end of the playbook run

Comment: No, the docs say that if you **don't** add `delegate_to` it will run on the first target. You claim the opposite.

Comment: ok I am not making myself clear ... I didnt like delegate_to because it produces wrong output on the PLAY RECAP so i removed delegate_to .... now I am not using delegate_to ... now i can control which host it runs on by changing the order of host groups ... when I do this the PLAY RECAP output is correct